# Unknown column on a Django fetched list

Tags: python, mysql, django

So I Have this Models that are generated from a MySQL base:

```
class Problem(models.Model):
    idproblem = models.IntegerField(db_column='idProblem', primary_key=True) 
    iduser = models.ForeignKey('User', db_column='idUser') 
    md5hash = models.CharField(db_column='md5Hash', max_length=32, blank=True)
    dateproblem = models.DateTimeField(db_column='dateProblem', blank=True, null=True)
    doneproblem = models.IntegerField(db_column='doneProblem', blank=True, null=True) 
    answerproblem = models.CharField(db_column='answerProblem', max_length=40, blank=True) 
    datedoneproblem = models.DateTimeField(db_column='dateDoneProblem', blank=True, null=True) 
    idsubproblem = models.IntegerField(db_column='idSubProblem', blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'problem'

class Subproblem(models.Model):
    idproblem = models.ForeignKey(Problem, db_column='idProblem')
    idsubproblem = models.IntegerField(db_column='idSubProblem') 
    stringsubproblem = models.CharField(db_column='stringSubProblem', max_length=8, blank=True)
    iduser = models.ForeignKey('User', db_column='idUser', blank=True, null=True)
    senddateproblem = models.DateTimeField(db_column='sendDateProblem', blank=True, null=True) 
    receivedateproblem = models.DateTimeField(db_column='receiveDateProblem', blank=True, null=True) 
    idstatus = models.ForeignKey(Status, db_column='idStatus') 
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'subproblem'
```

And then I have this View, wich is responsable for filtering the Problem and the SubProblem:

```
def pieceSender(request):
        #When I filter the Problem Model ther is no problem
    problems = Problem.objects.filter(doneproblem = False)
    problem = problems[0]

        # But when I try to do the same to the Subproblem Model the error below occours
    subproblems = Subproblem.objects.filter(idproblem = problem)
    print subproblems[0].idsubproblem

        # This is just here So that I can see the error on the Browser
    dados = {}  
    dados['status'] = 'OK'
    data_json = simplejson.dumps(dados)

     return HttpResponse(data_json)
```

This is the Error mentioned

```
OperationalError at /receivePiece/
     (1054, "Unknown column 'subproblem.id' in 'field list'")
     Request Method:    GET
     Request URL:   http://localhost:8000/receivePiece/
     Django Version:    1.6.2
     Exception Type:    OperationalError
     Exception Value: (1054, "Unknown column 'subproblem.id' in 'field list'")
     Exception Location:    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py in defaulterrorhandler, line 36
     Python Executable: C:\Python27\python.exe
     Python Version:    2.7.6
     Python Path:   
            ['D:\\Projetos\\sgpd',
            'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
            'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
            'C:\\Python27\\lib',
            'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
            'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
            'C:\\Python27',
            'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
     Server time:   Thu, 17 Apr 2014 02:36:18 -0300
```

Does this happen cause the SubProblem Model does not have a PrimaryKey?

If so how to I make Django recognise that this table is a Double PrimaryKey table?

Any Help is much apprecitated! =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is because you didn't specify a primary key in subproblem model and Django is expecting one. To resolve the problem, remove "managed" from the Meta and execute "django-admin syncdb", and everything should work now.

Comment: I removed the Managed from the meta.
And then I did a python manage.py syncdb.
But still the error happens

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say you have to delete the table as well to be recreated. :-)

Comment: I deleted the table, but for some reason Django is not creating the new table. So I droped the whole database and made a manage.py syncdb and the only tables that it is creating is the django ones. The table from my models are not being created.

Comment: I believe you forgot to remove from your models the "managed" that it is inside Meta class.

Comment: It was probably that, I Thought I Should remove it only from SubProblem, but Thank you! =D

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your model doesn't have primary key - Django assumes you have a pk column named id (auto generated) You could look into this app: https://github.com/simone/django-compositekey - it will allow you to define a composite pk.

Comment: Yeah, so it's definitely cause it does not have a Primary Key.
What I may do is put IdSubProblem as a Auto Increment PrimaryKey and just filter it by the IdProblem. It's not gonna be pretty cause eache problem generates 3844 SubProblems but at least it will work.

Comment: Or... You could use this lib I've given you url to :). I'm actually puzzled why @Juan's answer won't work in your case. Read about it here, maybe some idea will pop in your head :) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#managed

Comment: One more suggestions - amount of SubProblems isn't a good excuse to not having a PK on this table.

Comment: THe thing is it has a PK is just that Django does not recognize a CompositePK. I don't know why his sollution didn't work. I'm a Begginer to Django so I Don't know is manage.py syncdb the same as django-admin syncdb?

Comment: I would remove "idproblem" from "Problem" class, and "idsubproblem" from "Subproblem" class, and let Django do its work. Remember to remove tables and syncdb again. Or if you want to stay with columns idproblem and idsubproblem on each (instead id), define both as primary keys and the problem should be resolved.